# How to display in TextView really large text (several megs)?

Tags: android, textview, large-files

I need to display in scrollable TextView really large amount of text (up to several megabytes). It's pretty clear that one need to somehow chunk text and display it slice by slice. The only question how to do it technically. Anyone can advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options,

Chunk it in a list.

Chunk it by chapter and display over several activitys.

Display this list one item at a time with a next button.

Have a buffer and remove off the beginning as it is scrolled past the screen and add to the end as it is approaching the screen,

Really is your choice, come back when there's a problem with that choice ;-)